# ng-model does not load the initial data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am making an application that calculates the volume of a piece of furniture. In a form bind the height, width and depth to input elements.

like this.

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="input" 
       ng-model="data.size.height" ng-minlength="1.0" ng-maxlength="2.0" 
       min="1.0" max="2.0" step="0.01" required>
```

The problem is that the input elements do not load the initial data model. 
If the values ​​are changed by the user, the model is updated but the value is wrong.

The sample uses ui-router bootstrap ui-bootstrap

Here is the code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/QuVuyh?p=preview

Comment: What does the `the model is updated but the value is wrong.` mean? The value is something else, does not changed, or be undefined?

Comment: Your data are strings, not numbers, and then aren't shown by the `input[type=number]`. Remove the quotes around the number in `data.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank Blackhole comment I could solve the problem.

Replacing This:

```
{
    "id":"1234",
    "size": {
        "width": "0.70",
        "height": "1.40",
        "deep": "0.64"
    }
}
```

With this other:

```
{
    "id":"1234",
    "size": {
        "width": 0.70,
        "height": 1.40,
        "deep": 0.64
    }
}
```